# VBA Msgbox not displaying correct value from calculation

Tags: excel, vba, msgbox

My workbook has two sheets - main sheet and client's sheet. On the main sheet, users can input an ID, portfolio and select "remove from portfolio" where the entered ID will be removed from the main sheet and client's sheet. The client's sheet has a summary box that contains aggregated values based on the table in the clients sheet, and will automatically update once the ID has been removed. These values are Yield to Call, Yield to Maturity, Average Rating, and Duration.

For order of operations, the code will first take the values before the ID is removed, remove the ID, take the new values after the ID has been removed, and then calculate the changes so they can be displayed in a msgbox. For YTC, YTM, Rating, and Current yield, it works perfectly, but for duration it keeps saying the change is 0.00 even though I know that's not true. Here is the code:

```
CUSIP = Source_Data.Range("B3")
Selected_Portfolio = Source_Data.Range("B5")

With Sheets("Source_Data")
    Set MainTableRow = .Cells.Find(What:=CUSIP, After:=.Cells(8, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
End With

If MainTableRow Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "CUSIP does not exist in Source_Data table"
    Exit Sub
End If

If Selected_Portfolio = "Beth" Then
    With Sheets("Beth")
        Set PortfolioRow = .Cells.Find(What:=CUSIP, After:=.Cells(1, 2), LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        c = 1
        OldRating = Beth.Range("T5").Value
        OldCurrentYield = Beth.Range("T4").Value
        OldYTM = Beth.Range("T6").Value
        OldYTC = Beth.Range("T7").Value
        OldDuration = Beth.Range("T8").Value
    End With
End If

If PortfolioRow Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "CUSIP does not exist in selected portfolio"
    Exit Sub
End If

If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete " & CUSIP & " from " & Selected_Portfolio & "'s Portfolio?" & " This action cannot be undone.", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

m = MainTableRow.Row - 8
s = PortfolioRow.Row - 1

With Sheets("Source_Data")
    Set MainTable = Source_Data.ListObjects("MainTable")
    MainTable.ListRows(m).Delete
End With

If c = 1 Then
    With Sheets("Beth")
        Set PortfolioTable = Beth.ListObjects("Table38")
        PortfolioTable.ListRows(s).Delete
        NewRating = Beth.Range("T5").Value
        NewCurrentYield = Beth.Range("T4").Value
        NewYTM = Beth.Range("T6").Value
        NewYTC = Beth.Range("T7").Value
        NewDuration = Beth.Range("T8").Value
    End With
End If

If OldRating <> NewRating Then
    rc = 1
Else
    rc = 0
End If

If OldCurrentYield > NewCurrentYield Then
    ChangeCurrentYield = OldCurrentYield - NewCurrentYield
    StringCY = "decreased by"
ElseIf OldCurrentYield < NewCurrentYield Then
    ChangeCurrentYield = NewCurrentYield - OldCurrentYield
    StringCY = "increased by"
End If

If OldYTM > NewYTM Then
    ChangeYTM = OldYTM - NewYTM
    StringYTM = "decreased by"
ElseIf OldYTM < NewYTM Then
    ChangeYTM = NewYTM - OldYTM
    StringYTM = "increased by"
End If

If OldYTC > NewYTC Then
    ChangeYTC = OldYTC - NewYTC
    StringYTC = "decreased by"
ElseIf OldYTC < NewYTC Then
    ChangeYTC = NewYTC - OldYTC
    StringYTC = "increased by"
End If

If OldDuration > NewDuration Then
    ChangeDuration = OldDuration - NewDuration
    StringDuration = "decreased by"
ElseIf OldDuration < NewDuration Then
    ChangeDuration = NewDuration - OldDuration
    StringDuration = "increased by"
End If

If rc = 1 Then
    MsgBox "Succesfully Deleted: " & CUSIP & " From " & Selected_Portfolio & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Rating has changed from " & OldRating & " to " & NewRating & vbNewLine & "Current Yield has " & StringCY & " " & ChangeCurrentYield & " to " & NewCurrentYield & vbNewLine & "YTM has " & StringYTM & " " & ChangeYTM & " to " & NewYTM & vbNewLine & "YTC has " & StringYTC & " " & ChangeYTC & " to " & NewYTC & " from " & OldYTC & vbNewLine & "OAS Duration has " & StringDuration & " " & ChangeDuration & " to " & NewDuration & " from " & OldDuration
End If

If rc = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Succesfully Deleted: " & CUSIP & " From " & Selected_Portfolio & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Rating has not changed from " & OldRating & vbNewLine & "Current Yield has " & StringCY & " " & FormatPercent(ChangeCurrentYield, 3) & " to " & FormatPercent(NewCurrentYield, 2) & vbNewLine & "YTM has " & StringYTM & " " & FormatPercent(ChangeYTM, 3) & " to " & FormatPercent(NewYTM, 2) & vbNewLine & "YTC has " & StringYTC & " " & FormatPercent(ChangeYTC, 3) & " to " & FormatPercent(NewYTC, 2) & " from " & FormatPercent(OldYTC, 2) & vbNewLine & "OAS Duration has " & StringDuration & " " & Format(ChangeDuration, "0.0000") & " to " & Format(NewDuration, "0.000") & " from " & Format(OldDuration, "0.000")
End If
```

Comment: Did you force a recalculation prior to picking up the value

Comment: Can you not debug it with F8?

Comment: So when using F8, it says the variable OldDuration = Empty, but there is definitely a value in Beth.Range("T8").Value. I even checked to see if the value is a number by using "=count(T8)" and also isnumber(T8) and they both come back as 1 and true, respectively.

Comment: What is `Beth`, a worksheet codename? Do you observe that `OldDuration = Empty` on the line or after? Does the execution go inside `Selected_Portfolio = "Beth"`?

Comment: I would suggest looking to make sure the formula in cell T8 is as you expect.  If all the others are working there doesn't seem to be something wrong in the vba portion as much as something within the sheet/cell itself.